# Is 700c 25/32 iner tubes the same as 700c 18/25?

Tags: innertube

I'm trying to replace inner tubes on my bike but I got ones that do not match the one that I am taking out of a wheel.

Comment: We need to know what size your tyres are.

Comment: @carel I'd guess the two sizes are in the title, but not which is which.

Comment: @Criggie : If we assume that both tyres are 25mm, then it will be OK. But not if they are both either 23 or 28.

Comment: @Criggie Those are tube sizes, not tyre sizes.

Answer (score 4):

700 essentially refers to the diameter of the wheel, while the other two numbers give the range of tyre widths that the tube is suitable for. So 18-25 covers tyres between 18mm and 25 mm inclusive, while 25-32 would suit slightly wider tyres (25mm wide - 32mm wide inclusive) of the same wheel diameter.

So both tubes would suit a 700c x25 tyre as they overlap sizes there, but they aren’t the same per se

Comment: I've successfully used a 18-to-25mm tube in a 32 mm tyre.  In theory its fractionally lighter but is more stretched.  A wider tube in a smaller tyre runs the risk of pinching or folding on installation, yet will produce a slightly more puncture resistant wheel due to less stretch.  Both to sharps and to snake bites.